# PL/SQL Number rows with same ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm making an extract and want to number rows with the same values to have same row number. Example :

> ```
> TRN            Date      Product   ROW_Number
> ABC1         2015-06-15    001         1
> ABC1         2015-06-15    002         1 
> ABC1         2015-06-15    003         1
> DEF1         2015-06-15    001         2
> DEF1         2015-06-15    002         2
> ```

The rows with same TRN must have same row_number. Is this possible at all? If it can not be done in the script it's an option to do numbering in Deski, so if someone knows how I`ll be very thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`DENSE_RANK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm) analytic function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/502a6c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( TRN, "Date", Product ) AS
          SELECT 'ABC1', DATE '2015-06-15', '001' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'ABC1', DATE '2015-06-15', '002' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'ABC1', DATE '2015-06-15', '003' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'DEF1', DATE '2015-06-15', '001' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'DEF1', DATE '2015-06-15', '002' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT d.*,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY TRN, "Date" ) AS ROW_NUM
FROM   data d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/502a6c/1/0)**:

```
|  TRN |                   Date | PRODUCT | ROW_NUM |
|------|------------------------|---------|---------|
| ABC1 | June, 15 2015 00:00:00 |     001 |       1 |
| ABC1 | June, 15 2015 00:00:00 |     002 |       1 |
| ABC1 | June, 15 2015 00:00:00 |     003 |       1 |
| DEF1 | June, 15 2015 00:00:00 |     001 |       2 |
| DEF1 | June, 15 2015 00:00:00 |     002 |       2 |
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for PL/SQL, this can be done with plain SQL and a window function:

```
select trn, date, product, 
       dense_rank() over (order by trn) as rn
from the_table;
```